# Псевдоклассы javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Добрый день.

```
    var test = $('.menu li a').css('color');
    alert(test);
```

Выведет цвет ссылки, а как мне вывести цвет ссылки при наведении (hover)

```
    var test = $('.menu li a:hover').css('color');
    alert(test);
```

Не помогает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.menu li a').mouseover(function(){
   var test = $(this).css("color");
   alert(test);
})
```

Comment: При наведении выводит пустой алерт

Comment: мне нужно запихнуть цвет ссылки при наведении в переменную

Comment: Да, точно. Исправил http://jsbin.com/uwolij/1/edit